# Can't have same headphones paired on both Windows 11 and Ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, windows-11

I have a Windows 11 installed in dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04.

I have my bluetooth headphones (Sony 1000XM3) and I had them paired in Windows which worked all right. Then if I switch to Linux I can pair and connect to headphones there, no problem, but if I go back to Windows again, the bluetooth starts playing up.

First the heaphones don't connect automatically when the OS starts and then when I try to connect them manyally, they connect for only a brief moment and then disconnect again.

So the only thing that's been working for me is that I have to re-pair headphones every time I decide log into Windows, but it's obviously a huge pain.

Is there any way around this issue? Not sure how common it is really.

Answer (score 6):

1. Pair your bluetooth device(s) in Linux.
2. Reboot into Windows, and pair your same bluetooth device(s) in Windows.
3. Run regedt32.exe. Navigate to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys"
4. Right-click on the "Keys" folder in the lefthand pane of the path above, and select "Export." In the pop-up dialog, change "Save as type" to "Text files," be sure that the "Export range" radio button "Selected branch" is selected, and save the file to your choice of name and location. For this purpose it's convenient if you've already configured a drive partition that's shared between your two OS, but it's not absolutely necessary, as you can use a thumb drive to transfer the file as well. If you have trouble exporting the folder, right click on it, select Permissions, and add Users to the groups that can read and edit the folder.

*P.S. If you don't see keys then go on the [HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys] folder right click and click on 'Permissions' , add your windows user and give it 'Full Control' You should be able to see the pairing keys then.*

5. Now reboot into Linux.
6. Open a command prompt in Linux type sudo caja (if you're not running Linux with MATE, you may have a different file manager; substitute as necessary) and enter your password at the prompt. **This will open a file manager with SU rights, so handle with care ... I'm not responsible if you brick your system!**
7. Navigate to /var/lib/bluetooth. Inside of this folder you will see one or both of two things -- either a single folder named with a single MAC address (of your computer's bluetooth adapter) or multiple folders, each with its own MAC address, for each paired bluetooth device (the MAC address will be in the format XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX). If you find only the single folder, folders with those individual MAC addresses will be inside the first adapter folder.
8. Open the folder containing the MAC address of the device you wish to pair in dual-boot mode. Inside that folder will be one or two files ... the one you care about is the "info" file. Double-click on it and it will open in a text editor with SU rights -- that is, you'll be able to edit it and save it. (by the way, if you're not sure which device you're looking for, the "info" file contains the plain-English device name, so just open each one in turn till you find the right one).
9. Open a separate (non-SU) instance of your file manager, and use it to open the text file you saved from Windows in another pane. When you double-click on that file, Linux may ask if you want to execute or edit it ... choose to edit.
10. The Windows registry export will contain multiple stanzas (one for each device) that look like this (don't worry, I've changed to a bogus MAC and key):

> Value 1     Name:            0008e024d45e     Type:
> REG_BINARY     Data:               00000000   31 c0 08 fa 4f 7b d2 4c
>
> - 6f e1 7d ba 32 29 a9 a7  1À.ïO{ÒLoá}ºQ)©§

11. Find the stanza containing the value on the "Name:" line which corresponds the MAC address of the file you have open in the first (SU) pane. Note that in the Windows files, the format of the MAC address uses lower-case letters instead of upper-case, and there are no colons.
12. Your Bluetooth pairing key is the string in the line that begins "00000000" and ends with a bunch of gibberish. Don't copy either the zeros or the gibberish, just the string in-between containing the 16 hex codes with the dash in the middle.
13. Insert that key into the "Key=" line in your "info" file. You can copy and paste if you want (I did), but you need to change lower-case letters to upper-case, and delete all spaces and dashes. In the example above, the resulting line will look like this:

> Key=31C008FA4F7BD24C6FE17DBA3229A9A7

14. Now save the file, repeat for any additional devices. Reboot into Windows, your device should now work. Reboot into Linux, it should also work.

Good Luck

Comment: Improvement (for those who might not know): After step #13, still in Linux, restart the bluetooth service (sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service) and then try to connect the BT device. That way you can check that everything works correctly on the Linux side without restarting and rebooting into it again. Saves a bit of time. --- Otherwise thank you  @PRD RSD! Sharing the pairing key in all OSs is an elegant and scalable solution.

Answer (score 3):

There's a quite easy solution for this problem.
the problem is: Windows pairs with this bluetooth device as it's the manager of the internal bluetooth module of your laptop, however linux thinks so too.

They both have different pairing signagures.

an easy solution for this, change bluetooth mac address on linux

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 down
sudo bluemoon -A
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

now you have a new identity on linux.
pair with your device, note you have to do this on every restart
when you return to windows you won't have to repair again.

Comment: To anyone having the same issue, this solution worked best for me. Ubuntu 22.04 / Win 11 dual boot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your Bluetooth device has different pairing signagures between Linux and Windows.

The easiest way is to buy a Bluetooth USB dongle, disable your internal Bluetooth in Linux and disable your Bluetooth USB dongle in Windows.

Disabling internal Bluetooth in Linux:

- `lsusb`
- In my case my internal Bluetooth is `Bus 003 Device 008: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth`
- `sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth-hci.rules`
- `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0026", ATTR{authorized}="0"`

Disabling Bluetooth USB dongle in Windows:

- Go to Device Manager
- Expand "Bluetooth" section
- Connect/Disconnect your Bluetooth USB dongle to identify it on the list
- Right-click it and Disable device

Now you have different Bluetooth MACs in Windows/Linux, and auto-pair should work hassle-free.